# How to know if it is a memory bug when a program crashes while running whith a display "the program has stopped working"

Tags: c++, cuda

How to know if it is a memory problem when a program crashes while running whith a display "the program has stopped working"

My program crashes a lot and I cannot find any memory problems.

What other than memory problems crashes a program?

Comment: Does it crash during the usage, on startup or in the end?

Comment: Have you tried running your program in a debugger?

Comment: During runtime... just "windows has stopped working...." ... no other help text

Comment: Implement logging in your application, and inspect logs after each crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually when u don't dis-allocate used memory by pointers, programs tend to crash at the end.
Not having enough memory space crashes Cuda programs.

Other includes using out of bounds array...both in host and device in case of cuda.

Try and use exception handlers as far as possible so that you can trace your error.

in your case, since it stops in runtime...try and use a debugger. you will find the mistake. there are debuggers for cuda as well. you need to select one thread and follow the trace.
Make sure you dont use out of bounds arrays in threads as well.
+